# Models aren't joining

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-model

I have 4 tables:

- wizards (id, name)
- pages (id, page_number, wizard_id)
- modules (id, name)
- modules_pages(id, page_id, module_id, wizard_id)

**The models are baked defaults.**

A Wizard has a Page, a Page has a Module. modules_pages is a junction table. I cannot get a list of modules when I display an array from wizard or pages that is filtered by the current wizard_id of the page, or one that I pass. It just displays the modules multiple times.

---

### Page Model

```
    public $belongsTo = array(
    'Wizard' => array(
        'className' => 'Wizard',
        'foreignKey' => 'wizard_id',
    ),
);
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Module' => array(
        'className' => 'Module',
        'joinTable' => 'modules_pages',
        'foreignKey' => 'page_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'module_id',
        'unique' => 'keepExisting',
    )
);
```

### Module Model

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Page' => array(
        'className' => 'Page',
        'joinTable' => 'modules_pages',
        'foreignKey' => 'module_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'page_id',
        'unique' => 'keepExisting',
    ),
);

public $hasOne = array(
    'CodeReference' => array(
        'className' => 'CodeReference',
        'foreignKey' => 'code_reference_id',
    ),
);
```

### Wizard Model

```
    public $hasMany = array(
    'Page' => array(
        'className' => 'Page',
        'foreignKey' => 'wizard_id',
        'dependent' => false,
        'conditions' => 'ModulesPage.wizard_id = Wizard.id',
    )
);
```

---

### The Controller

```
$this->loadModel('Page');
    $this->Page->recursive = 1;
    $options = array('Page.wizard_id' => $wizard_id);
    $page = $this->Page->find('first', $options);
    $this->set('page');

    $this->loadModel('ModulesPage');
    $this->ModulesPage->recursive = 2;
    $options = array('ModulesPage.wizard_id ' => $wizard_id,
                     'ModulesPage.page_number' => $page_number,
                     'ModulesPage.enabled' => 1);
    $modules = $this->ModulesPage->find('all', $options);
```

Comment: Side note: if you don't have values to set, e.g. fields, order, limit etc, then don't define them as blank - it's just cluttering up your code (unless you are trying to override defaults).

Comment: Don't use recursive.  Set it to `public $recursive = -1;` in your AppModel, then use Cake's Containable Behavior.

Comment: the variable $option are options or conditions?

Comment: conditions. The convention on my team has been to place conditions in a variable above find(). I think the Cake manual uses '$options' as the variable name, which is where we get.

Comment: Don't you have to put that options array inside another array with key 'conditions'? Otherwise it won't work
i.e. after defining $options, add on a new line: 
$options = array('conditions' => $options);

Answer (score 0):

Start by setting the following in your AppModel:
    public $recursive = -1;

What Controller are you putting that code in? You shouldn't need to use loadModel - because you have joined the models together in the model files, you can access like this.

```
// access Module model from within PagesController
$this->Page->Module->find('all', $options);
```

There is also an error in your $options set-up. Conditions are provided in an array but they need to be inside another array called 'conditions', e.g.

```
$options = array(
    'conditions' => array(
        //conditions go here
    )
);
```

Finally, after turning off recursive you need to enable containable behaviour.  Change the $options array I've just given above as follows (this example would get all Pages along with their Wizards and Modules)

```
$options = array(
    'conditions' => array(
        //conditions go here
    ),
    'contain' => array(
        'Wizard',
        'Module'
    )
);
$data = $this->Page->find('all', $options);
```

You can further define additional options for the query with other array keys, e.g. 'order', 'group', 'limit', etc.